# Parse Incoming JSON directly into DTO with dynamic key

Tags: java, json, spring, elasticsearch, dto

I am trying to parse the data returned from Elastic search into a java class. The elastic search is returning the data in the form given below:

```
"aggregations": {
  "aggregationName": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": 439,
           "doc_count": 7,
           "nestedAggregationName": {
              "value": 5
           }
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

Here the "aggregationName" and "nestedAggregationName" names are dynamic, means they can be anything, so how can I manage this is my class? I want to parse directly the data returned into DTOs.

**EDIT:** I was able to parse "aggregationName" in a generic manner by making a class as below:

```
public Class Aggregation{
     private Map<String, AggregationModel> aggregation;

     //with getters and setters.
}
```

So whatever the "aggregationName" was, it was parsed easily and AggregationModel contains the fields corresponding to "aggregationName". How can I solve this problem for **"nestedAggregationName"**?

Please help.

Comment: I suggest you use [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest) or the official [Java client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html), both of which will parse the aggregation results into maps that you can explore.

Comment: @Val or as an alternative to Jest, he can use the official low level Java-REST client: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest.html

Comment: @JonyD The low-level REST client is only available for ES 5 onwards, so if he runs that, then OK. In the end, he can use whatever he feels most confortable using, now he has three options ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I fumbled upon the same problem some time back, and unfortunately the java client does not support aggregations response well(please correct me if I am wrong).
Following is what I came up with after multiple rounds of trail-error approach, let me know if this helps.

```
private Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, Long>>> buildAggregationsFromResult(SearchResults resultSet, Set aggregationsName) {
    Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, Long>>> aggregations = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Map.Entry<String, Long>>>();
    if (null != resultSet.getAggregations()) {
        Map<String, Aggregation> aggregationMap = resultSet.getAggregations().asMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Aggregation> aggregationEntry : aggregationMap.entrySet()) {
            fetchBucketTermsFromAggregations(aggregationEntry,aggregations, aggregationsName);
        }
    }
    return aggregations;
}

private List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> fetchBucketTermsFromAggregations(Map.Entry<String, Aggregation> aggregationEntry, Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, Long>>> aggregations, Set<String> aggregationsName) {
    Terms terms = null;
    List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    if (aggregationEntry.getValue() instanceof InternalNested) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Aggregation> aggregationEntryNested : ((InternalNested) aggregationEntry.getValue()).getAggregations().asMap().entrySet()) {
            pairs = fetchBucketTermsFromAggregations(aggregationEntryNested, aggregations, aggregationsName);
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(pairs) && aggregationsName.contains(aggregationEntry.getKey()))
                aggregations.put(aggregationEntry.getKey(), pairs);

        }
    } else if (aggregationEntry.getValue() instanceof InternalFilters) {
        for (InternalFilters.Bucket buckets : ((InternalFilters) aggregationEntry.getValue()).getBuckets()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Aggregation> nestedAggregations : buckets.getAggregations().asMap().entrySet()) {
                pairs = fetchBucketTermsFromAggregations(nestedAggregations, aggregations, aggregationsName);
                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(pairs) && aggregationsName.contains(aggregationEntry.getKey()) )
                    aggregations.put(aggregationEntry.getKey(), pairs);
            }
        }
    } else {
        terms = (Terms) aggregationEntry.getValue();
        if (null != terms ) {
            Collection<Terms.Bucket> buckets = terms.getBuckets();
            for (Terms.Bucket bucket : buckets) {
                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(bucket.getAggregations().asList()))
                    pairs.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Long>(bucket.getKeyAsString(), ((InternalReverseNested)bucket.getAggregations().asList().get(0)).getDocCount()));
                else
                    pairs.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Long>(bucket.getKeyAsString(), bucket.getDocCount()));
            }
        }

        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(pairs) && aggregationsName.contains(aggregationEntry.getKey()))
            aggregations.put(aggregationEntry.getKey(), pairs);
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

I know this looks a little clumsy, but may serve your case. Let me know otherwise.